# Query and Display referrer details

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website built with PHP and mysqli and now I am building administration panel for this website. I am facing some difficulties for querying and displaying referral data I do not have any idea how to do it.

I have a table called user_registration and the fields include, user_name, email, password, referrer. Whenever any of the registered member is referring others the referrer username will be saved in the field "referrer".

Now what I want is to fetch only the rows of the members who has referrals (means referred by my registered members) and also want to count how many referrals a member have and echo it.

For example: I have 20 registered members and from it 5 members have some referrals so I want to query and echo those member's username who has referrals and also count how many referrals they have:

```
    Member's Username         Total Referrals
        user7                       8
        user6                       6
        user1                       5
        user9                       3
        user5                       2
```

Comment: Do you have the functionality ready which captures the referrals and save the data in the database and you just want to pull only those users who have referred someone? OR You haven't any functionality ready yet and you want a complete solution?

Comment: I already have a working functionality which post the data to the database I just want to pull the data of those members who has referrals and also want to count how many referrals each member has as mentioned above.

I just want the PHP code which can pull the data according to the instructions mentioned.

Comment: Given your comments, this is another request for free work, and would have been too broad even in 2014. For the most part, we need a specific problem or code for Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving an idea in short which may help you to complete your project -

Suppose your site URL is `http://yoursite.com`.

1) Whenever a user is registered, you can generate a random key for that user and save  it in the database for that particular user. e.g. user1 => `abc123`

2) Now, you can tell your user (may be on a page after their successful registration) that his/her referrer id is `http://yoursite.com/?ref_id=abc123` (by appending it as a new parameter)

or if your register page is `http://yoursite.com/register` then `http://yoursite.com/register/?ref_id=abc123`

3) Now, they can share this link to their friends, colleague etc to whomever they want.

4) Now, suppose if a person (may be his friend to whom the user1 referred) clicks on the above link. He will land on your site with the parameter 'ref_id' appended.

5) Just using $_REQUEST['ref_id'] or $_GET['ref_id'], capture its value and store it in a SESSION variable. This you can do on the main page of your site e.g. index.php

6) Now, if that user does the registration, you can make an entry in the database that he has been referred once by the user who has referrer id `abc123` i.e. user1.

7) So, you can add `count = 1` for user1. If more people come with the same value for the 'ref_id' parameter, you can keep on increment the count.

8) If no such parameter is exists when user lands on your site, then that means he has not referred by anyone. So, that means he is the first kind of user i.e. user in point no. 1).

9) You may also need to take care of some validation part at some places in this.

EDIT:

```
SELECT user_name, referrer FROM user_registration WHERE referrer > 0;
```

Assuming that you have a proper insert query ready which gives you the result as you shown the table in your question.

Comment: Thank you WisdmLabs for your response but as I have already stated I just only want the PHP code that can query and fetch and echo the data according to my needs. As you have mentioned about the parameters and validation points I already have those in my code for posting into my database I just want to pull the data. If you can help me please give a example to pull the data for my needs mentioned in above. Once again thank you for your response.

Comment: So from as per point no. 7 from my answer, you can run `insert` query (may be in your user table) for increment count and finally run a `select` query to display them wherever you want. Since you haven't listed and piece of your code. It's pretty difficult to give you an exact code. However, I have edited my answer with a sample code. See if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be. Make a new column in your user table like "totalreferrals". In this way you can easily keep track of the amount of people they have referred. You could also make a new table "referral". In here you would save the referrals name, the new persons name and a timestamp or something. Now it is even possible to make queries for different periods.

I think that you need to rethink about your database setup, instead of trying to make way to complicated queries, to make your database work.